# Porque no me modifica mi producto de mi BD en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

tengo un api que me sirve para modificar la cual es la siguiente:

```
app.put('/menu/:folioproducto', (req, res) => {
    const { folioproducto } = req.params;
    const { nombreplatillo, precio } = req.body;

const query = 'UPDATE menu SET nombreplatillo = ?, precio = ? WHERE folioproducto = ?';
connection.query(query, [nombreplatillo, precio, folioproducto], (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('Error al actualizar el platillo:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error al actualizar el platillo' });
    } else {
        res.json({ message: 'Platillo actualizado exitosamente' });
    }
});
```

});

en esa api ingreso a una BD llamada restaurante la cual tiene una tabla llamada menu y tiene folioproducto, nombreplatillo y precio. Los cuales solo quiero modificar el precio y el nombre.
Tengo un componente en react donde mando a llamar a esa api, en ese componente tengo esto:

```
const [nombre, setNombre] = useState('');
const [precio, setPrecio] = useState('');
```

donde el usuario ingresa los nuevos datos y esos datos los mando aqui:

```
const GuardarClick = () => {
        if (selectedPlatillo && nombre !== '' && precio !== '') {
            axios
                .put(`http://localhost:3000/menu/${selectedPlatillo}`, {
                    nombreplatillo: nombre,
                    precio: precio,
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    Swal.fire('¡Éxito!', response.data.message, 'success');
                    setShowModal(false);
                    obtenerPlatillos(); // Para actualizar la lista de platillos después de modificar uno.
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    Swal.fire('¡Error!', 'Error al modificar el platillo', 'error');
                    console.error('Error al modificar el platillo:', error);
                });
        } else {
            Swal.fire('¡Advertencia!', 'Completa todos los campos antes de guardar', 'warning');
        }
    };
```

al principio me dice que si se guardaron los datos, pero al final siguen igual, estoy usando axios, les muestro el codigo completo del componente.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Styles/ModificarMenu.css';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import axios from 'axios';

const ModificarMenu = () => {

const [platillos, setPlatillos] = useState([]);
const [selectedPlatillo, setSelectedPlatillo] = useState(null);
const [nombre, setNombre] = useState('');
const [precio, setPrecio] = useState('');
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    obtenerPlatillos();
}, []);



const obtenerPlatillos = () => {
    axios
        .get('http://localhost:3000/menu')
        .then((response) => {
            setPlatillos(response.data.nombresPlatillos);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error al obtener los platillos:', error);
        });
};


const handlePlatilloClick = (platillo) => {
    setSelectedPlatillo(platillo);
    setNombre('');
    setPrecio('');
    setShowModal(true);
};

const handleNombreChange = (event) => {
    setNombre(event.target.value);
};

const handlePrecioChange = (event) => {
    setPrecio(event.target.value);
};


const handleGuardarClick = () => {
    if (selectedPlatillo && nombre !== '' && precio !== '') {
        axios
            .put(`http://localhost:3000/menu/${selectedPlatillo}`, {
                nombreplatillo: nombre,
                precio: precio,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                Swal.fire('¡Éxito!', response.data.message, 'success');
                setShowModal(false);
                obtenerPlatillos(); // Para actualizar la lista de platillos después de modificar uno.
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                Swal.fire('¡Error!', 'Error al modificar el platillo', 'error');
                console.error('Error al modificar el platillo:', error);
            });
    } else {
        Swal.fire('¡Advertencia!', 'Completa todos los campos antes de guardar', 'warning');
    }
};




return (
    <div className="ModificarMenu">
        <h2>Modificar Menú</h2>
        <div className="platillos-list">
            <ul>
                {platillos.map((platillo) => (
                    <li
                        key={platillo}
                        className="platillo"
                        onDoubleClick={() => handlePlatilloClick(platillo)}
                    >
                        {platillo}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
        {showModal && (
            <div className="modal">
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <h3>Modificar platillo: {selectedPlatillo}</h3>
                    <div className="form-fields">
                        <label htmlFor="nombre">Nuevo nombre:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="nombre"
                            className="input-field"
                            value={nombre}
                            onChange={handleNombreChange}
                        />
                        <br />
                        <label htmlFor="precio">Nuevo precio:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="precio"
                            className="input-field"
                            value={precio}
                            onChange={handlePrecioChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="buttons">
                        <button className="cancelar-btn" onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>
                            Cancelar
                        </button>
                        <button className="guardar-btn" onClick={handleGuardarClick}>
                            Guardar cambios
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
);
};

export default ModificarMenu;
```

donde primero tengo la funcion obtenerPlatillos la cual usa un api que me muestra todos los platillos guardados en mi BD y al darle doble click a uno salen los campos de modificar. Pero como menciones no me guarda los cambios, saben cual seria el error

Comment: Ya hiciste debug de tu código? ya validaste del lado del frontend que la ruta llamada sea la correcta? que los parámetros enviados sean los correctos? ya validaste desde el backend que si se esté ejecutando la ruta?